# _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serialization

**Will `@JsonSerialization` take care of the List mapping if there exists a List in Flutter?**

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Content {
  Content(this.contentItems);

  @JsonKey(name: "content-items")
  List<Movie> contentItems;

  factory Content.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ContentFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ContentToJson(this);
}
```

In the above class do we need to manually convert the json to list of Movie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the required methods and mapping will be generated by **@JsonSerializable** annotation. We will have to provide the  **_$ContentFromJson(json)** and **_$ContentToJson(this)** as given in the question.

For me this was not working initially..
After generating the g.dart files also it was not behaving properly.Then after restarting the machine I was able to get the expected result. Don't know what was causing the error yet.